# How to indicate a blank space in Column Validation?

Tags: calculated-column-formula, column-validation

I have a column called `Machine #`.  There is a space between Machine and the # symbol.  I think the space might be causing an issue - Sharepoint does not seem to like having a space in the Column Validation section.

How to I type `Machine #` in such a way that Sharepoint will accept me using a column with a space in the column name?  For instance I've tried `Machine%20#`.

[image: Machine column definition and column-validation]

Comment: Hey - thanks for the Answer and the down-vote Gopal!  I'm keeping this question, as it is slightly different to my original question.  Another user might benefit from this.

Comment: this downvote is not from me :P

Comment: Ah!  Sorry about that...  That's why we should never assume anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround which achieves the result I need.  Gopal Zadafiya provided this tidy trick:

- Create the column with only name "Machine" and save.  Then change the display
  name to "Machine #" afterwards. Validation will work after changing
  the display name too.

Therefore, the Column Validation is simple and `=LEN([Machine #])=6` is accepted by Sharepoint.